# Using GIT in Plesk for a laravel project

Tags: laravel, git, version-control, plesk

I currently have a web application installed on my 'domain.com'. My server makes use of Plesk. What I then did was copy my app on a subdomain called 'test.domain.com' The second one is what I use for development work and once I have coded and tested, I manually copy the files across to the folders in the 'domain.com' project.
It is a very tedious process and I sometimes loose track of changes. My background is electronics engineering where I did some embedded programming in C. I am familiar with SVN version control and I am aware how version control can make my life easier.

Does anyone know what I can do to implement GIT or other alternatives to simplify my development process?

Answer (score 0):

You can link a git repo on Plesk, and also you can choose the branch you want to pull too.
Link the master to branch to your domain.com root directory and another one like "develop" on you test.domain.com.

Plesk will give you a webhook link you can add on your git repo to auto-pull when you pushed.

You can add some after pull command on plesk, like a schema update for your laravel project too.